# Search for strange characters in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am loading a .csv file in an Oracle table but I have seen that I have strange characters in one of the fields such as: ¬, ä

How can I validate that this does not happen in the other fields like varchar2?

Comment: Sounds like you have a character set mismatch during the load. Are you really asking how to avoid that - in which case we'd need details of how you are doing it, along with DB info like the character set, data types etc. and client/OS character set,

Comment: That's the wrong approach. Check the character set of the CSV-File and configure your import accordingly. How do you import the CSV?

Comment: Why do you consider `, ä` as "strange" characters?

Answer (score 0):

For each of your varchar2 columns, you need to search for multi bytes characters like below. Lengthb function returns the size of a string in bytes.
[asktom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=identify-multi-byte-characters)

```sql
with t as (
select 'àäêsgdkf fdd' col1 from dual union all
select 'mno¬ijk' col1 from dual union all
select 'abc fdd' col1 from dual
)
select col1
from t
where length(col1) < lengthb(col1)
;

COL1
----------
àäêsgdkf fdd
mno¬ijk
```

Comment: This query does no work if you database runs with single-byte character set, e.g. `WE8MSWIN1252`. However, this *could* be the case here.